# What are the differences between the regular and Collector's Edition of GTA 5?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

What are the differences between the regular and Collector's Edition of GTA 5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[From Gamestop:](http://www.gamestop.com/ps3/games/grand-theft-auto-v-gamestop-exclusive-collectors-edition/109638)

**Grand Theft Auto V GameStop Exclusive Collector's Edition**

- Full retail copy of Grand Theft Auto V (includes GTA V Online)
- Collectible SteelBook with Exclusive Artwork - features custom color and metallic treatments to bring out the detail of the Michael, Trevor and Franklin artwork created exclusively for this SteelBook
- Blueprint Map - exclusive, 21.5" x 26.75" map displays a blueprint view of Los Santos and Blaine County
- Special Ability Boost - Michael, Franklin and Trevor each have a unique special ability. With this boost, the special ability bar will generate 25% faster
- Stunt Plane Trials - single-player Stunt Plane Trials let players take on additional aerial challenges spread throughout Los Santos and Blaine County
- Bonus Outfits, Tattoos and More - Michael, Franklin and Trevor get bonus outfits in their wardrobes, character specific tattoos at tattoo parlors, and special deals from shopkeepers across Los Santos and Blaine County
- Additional Weapons - when visiting Ammunition stores in single-player, merchants will have special weapons in their inventory available for free: the Pistol .50, Bullpup Shotgun and melee Hammer.
- Grand Theft Auto V Security Deposit Bag with Logo Key - inspired by the heists in Grand Theft Auto V, this custom 10.75" x 8.5" money bag features a pop-up style lock and laser cut logo key to secure important items. The reverse side features a pressed Rockstar Games logo on the security mount with a framed ID window
- Grand Theft Auto V New Era 9FIFTY Snapback Cap - this exclusive New Era 9FIFTY cap features an embroidered Los Santos logo on the front, a stitched, black Rockstar Games logo on the wearer's left side, a Grand Theft Auto V' logo applique on the opposite side, and snapback closure for an adjustable fit
- Custom Characters for Grand Theft Auto Online - get classic Grand Theft Auto characters to use within the Grand Theft Auto Online Character Creation System
- Unique Vehicles and Garage Property - players will instantly receive a garage to store custom vehicles. In single-player, the garage will be stocked with the 1930's style Hotknife hotrod and the CarbonRS sports bike. In Grand Theft Auto Online, players will get the high-end Khamelion electric car.

[image]

**Grand Theft Auto (Regular Version)**

- Full retail copy of Grand Theft Auto V (includes GTA V Online)
- Two sided map of the Los Santos and Blaine County

*Also note the price difference between both versions, subject to vary*